# Partial Cross-correlation in R

Tags: r, cross-correlation

I think the title is fairly self-explanatory. I want to compute the cross-correlation between two time series controlled for the values at other lags. I can't find any existing R code to do this, and I'm not at all confident enough in my knowledge of statistics (or R) to try to write something myself. It would be analogous to the partial autocorrelation function, just for the cross-correlation instead of the autocorrelation.

If it helps at all, my larger objective is to look for lagged correlations between different measurements of a physical system (to start with, flux and photon index from gamma ray measurements of blazars), with the goal of building a general linear model to try to predict flaring events.

Comment: I'm a bit out of depth here, but you can probably look at the documentation for  function `acf`.  Especially the example using Union `acf(ts.union(mdeaths, fdeaths))`

Comment: Edit: Sorry, a  union is not going to do any good in this case.

Comment: Unless you have a specific, implementable way to calculate the values you want, this probably isn't the best place to ask your question. If you need help with the analysis of your data, you would be better off asking about statistical methods at [stats.se].

Comment: I will post it there, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292271/does-the-partial-version-of-the-cross-correlation-function-exist-if-so-how-c)  to my own question (same as the one you posted).

You can make use of the `pacf` function in R, extending it to a matrix with 2 or more time series. I have checked results between the multivariate `acf` and `ccf` functions and they yield the same results, so the same can be concluded about the multivariate `pacf`and the non-existing `pccf`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this work,

```
  pccf <- function(x,y,nlags=7,partial=TRUE){
  
  # x (numeric): variable that leads y
  # y (numeric): variable of interest
  # nlags (integer): number of lags (uncluding zero)
  # partial (boolean): partial or absolute correlation
    
  # trim y
  y <- y[-(1:(nlags-1))]
  
  # lagged matrix of x
  x_lagged <- embed(x,nlags)
  
  # process for each lag
  rho <- lag <- NULL
  for(i in 1:(nlags)){
    
    if(partial){
      # residuals of x at lag of interest regressed on all other lags of x
      ex <- lm(x_lagged[,i] ~ x_lagged[,-i])$residuals
      
      # residuals of y regressed on all lags of x but the one of interest
      ey <- lm(y ~ x_lagged[,-i])$residuals
    }else{
      ex <- x_lagged[,i]
      ey <- y
    }
    
    # calculate correlation
    rho[i] = cor(ex,ey, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
    lag[i] = i-1
  }
  
  return(
    tibble(lag=lag, rho=rho) %>%
           arrange(lag)
    )
  
}

# test
n <- 200 # count
nlag <- 6 # number of lags
x <- as.numeric(arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=c(phi=0.9)),sd=1)) # simulate times series x
y <- lag(x,nlag) + rnorm(n,0,0.5) # simulate y to lag x
y <- y[(nlag+1):n] # remove NAs from lag
x <- x[(nlag+1):n] # align with y

pccf(x,y,nlags=10,partial=FALSE) %>%
 mutate(type='Cross correlation') %>%
 bind_rows(
  pccf(x,y,nlags=10,partial=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(type='Partial cross correlation') 
) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_col(aes(-lag,rho),width=0.1) +
facet_wrap(~type,scales='free_y', ncol=1) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=-10:0) +
theme_bw(base_size=20)
```